# Nearby Messages Api successfully subscribed but onFound never called for Registered Google Beacon

Tags: android, beacon

I have been trying out Nearby API for detecting beacons in my Android app. Have followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started and https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages

The connection to GoogleAPI Client is initiated on click of a button on app (for explicit intent) and subscription to Nearby Messages is called in the onConnected callback.

```
//Inside onCreate
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                
            startNearby();
        }
    });


private void startNearby() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("Google_Api_Client: It was connected on (onConnected) function, working as it should.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Google_Api_Client: It was NOT connected on (onConnected) function, It is definetly bugged.");
    }
    subscribe();
}
private void subscribe() {
    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            System.out.println("On Found: "+messageAsString);
            adapter.add("FOUND: "+messageAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            System.out.println("On Lost: "+messageAsString);
            adapter.add("LOST: "+messageAsString);
        }
    };
    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
            .build();
    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, options).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
           //     Log.i(TAG, "Subscribed successfully.");
                System.out.println("DONE. Subscribed successfully." +status);
                adapter.add("Subscribing done. "+status);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR. Could not subscribe, status = " + status);
        //        logAndShowSnackbar("Could not subscribe, status = " + status);
         //       mSubscribeSwitch.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the ResultCallback of Nearby.messages.subscribe call, I am getting success in the response status object-

```
I/System.out: Google_Api_Client: It was connected on (onConnected) function, working as it should.
I/System.out: DONE. Subscribed successfully.Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}
```

For the beacons, I am using Beacon Simulator app on Android Play store to simulate Eddystone UID beacon. I have registered two beacons using Beacon Tools app and can  see the beacons active on Google Beacon Dashboard.

**The issue is that the onFound / onLost callbacks are never called in my app.** Please note that the beacons are detectable by a Beacon Simulator app (on Android) as well the Google Beacon Tools app (under the Registered beacons nearby section).

Will really appreciate any help on what I might be doing wrong here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        startNearby();
    }
});

mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFound(Message message) {
        String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
        Log.d(null, "Found message: " + messageAsString);
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Found message: " + messageAsString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLost(Message message){
        String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
        Log.d(null, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString);
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

void startNearby() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();
}

private void subscribe() {
    Log.i("", "Subscribing...");
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Subscribing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
                .build();
        // Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, options);
        Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, options);/* */
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    subscribe();
}
```